# c# Is there an annotation to override default property name bindings?

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json response that I want to convert to an object `Detail`. So I used `var detail = json.toObject<Detail>();` but one of the property names on the json is `Customer.Age` so I need to override the binding for the property `CustomerAge` so that when converting between the json and Detail it knows `Customer.Age` is `CustomerAge`. Is there some annotation for this?

Comment: Since you did not mention which JSON library you are using, I will just assume that it is the most popular one (json.net) and close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for. Thanks!